# Unreleased Resource: Unmanaged Object

Tags: c#, .net

The function ProcessRequest() in CaptchaHandler.ashx fails to properly dispose of
unmanaged system resources allocated by Font() and SolidBrush()

```
    oGraphics.DrawString
            (
                //Text
            sCaptchaText.Substring(i, 1),
                //Random Font Name and Style
            new Font(aFontNames[oRandom.Next(aFontNames.Length - 1)],
               aFontEmSizes[oRandom.Next(aFontEmSizes.Length - 1)],
               aFontStyles[oRandom.Next(aFontStyles.Length - 1)]),
                //Random Color (Darker colors RGB 0 to 100)
            new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(oRandom.Next(0, 100),
               oRandom.Next(0, 100), oRandom.Next(0, 100))),
            x,
            oRandom.Next(10, 40)
            );
            oGraphics.ResetTransform();
```

help me how to relese the memory use by Font() and SolidBrush()

Comment: Define "fails", please. If you mean exception, then post exception details here. Also note, that `Dispose` doesn't release memory.

Answer (score 0):

Correct usage of graphic functions must look like this:

```
byte[] bytes = null;
using (System.Drawing.Image image = new Bitmap(w, h))
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
    {
        g.DrawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, w, h);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
            bytes = ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
return bytes;
```

Make sure you wrap your objects with `using` keyword.